# By which preposition is "equality" followed:on,of,or in?

Tags: prepositions

I am writing an article to discuss whether a recent reform of college entrance examination in my country equally benefits every students,so I give a title that "Education **equality on** The New College Entrance Examination System Reform". But somebody told me this title wasn't decent enough,since the preposition following equality should be "**in**" or "**of**",rather than "**on**".

So I am curious about which preposition should be used.Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Of" is preferable.

Though according to the [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equality%20of%2C%20equality%20in%2C%20equality%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequality%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cequality%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cequality%20on%3B%2Cc0) all the prepositions are possible.

Here's an example from [Reverso.context.net](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/equality):

"The project is divided into three segments:  equality in national organizations,   equality in regional and structural policy,  and equality in the development of the immediate neighbourhood."

But:

"There will also  be equality of  status, equality of opportunity  and equality before the law."

As about the title l would use "[in](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Equality%20in%20law%2C%20equality%20on%20law&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CEquality%20in%20law%3B%2Cc0)".

Comment: thanks for the answer and the method which lets me know how to find the answer :)

Comment: I would recommend "in"!

Comment: Well,sorry, I am a bit confused now...If "of" is used much more extensive than "in",according to graph,why the latter is recommended?

Comment: For the particular case I would say "in". I think the main idea of your research is to analyze the equal education which is stated "IN" this reform.

Comment: wow,I get your point! Thanks!